# How do you include an external library in your own project for C++?

Tags: .net, c++, shared-libraries, poco

So I'm quite new to C++, I've basically been coding it all semester for a class. For our final project, we made an email client in C++ with .NET, and to do all the email sending and receiving, we went with using the POCO email client.

Now, basically in order to use the POCO library, I've compiled it and done a number of things, such as adding the includes and libraries into the project using the path to where I compiled (on the desktop..), and I also had to add the path to the windows path.

SO, my question is, if I want to be able to package the POCO libraries into my project, how am I going to be able to do that? I can't really find a tutorial for this anywhere, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks! :)

Comment: It depending on the packaging mechanism you choose - please  give details as to how you're going to package the app.

Comment: Well this is the first app I've made.. but basically our prof is going to compile it herself in Visual Studio. Although I'd prefer if if the POCO libraries didn't have to be compiled, since they take abour an hour to compile!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio, there should be some info in the MSDN Help Center. Here is the [online version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384835.aspx) for VS2008 from the MSDN library.

Answer (score 1):

Create the helper POCOs in a dll and place these in a known location under the project directory - called say "OtherAssemblies". then in your project add references to these dlls using Add reference on the project r-click menu. then test. After completion. Give the prof the whole directory with project she can open the project and compile.

Make it easy on her - put a zip of the POCOs source code in same directory she can see it with out having to ask for them if she needs to but at the same time avoiding compiling.